# React fetch does not parse the response coming from the spring boot rest controller

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, cors, fetch

Hey guys i have a spring boot application that authenticate user and a react application with login page. I send basic authentication request with react fetch but it generates the following output. I think the problem may cause due to cors policy. When i change the endpoint in react code it works with other apis but my api does not parse the json

[image]

Here is my Spring boot configuration class:

```
package com.adamsware.securityProject.security;

import com.adamsware.securityProject.security.filter.JwtTokenGeneratorFilter;
import com.adamsware.securityProject.security.filter.JwtTokenValidatorFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /*
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");

         */
        //buradaki kod sayesinde springin sessionid oluşurturmasını engelliyoruz.
        //burada birazdan kendi session managementımızı kendimiz yapıcaz.
        //kendi token managementımızı
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfiguration()).and()
                //.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler).ignoringRequestMatchers("/contact","/register").csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
                .csrf().disable()
                //.addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/login").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/auth/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/auth/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration () {

        return request -> {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
            //exposed headers token ürettiğimiz için gönderiyoruz.ders85
            configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
            return configuration;
        };
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller class

```
package com.adamsware.securityProject.controller;

import com.adamsware.securityProject.model.Authority;
import com.adamsware.securityProject.model.User;
import com.adamsware.securityProject.security.SecurityConstants;
import com.adamsware.securityProject.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"})
public class   AuthController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(UserService userService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    //TODO POST MAPPING UNAUTHORIZED
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        ResponseEntity<?> response;
        try {
            String hashPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
            user.setPassword(hashPassword);
            Authority authority = new Authority();
            authority.setName(SecurityConstants.ROLE_USER);
            authority.setUser(user);
            Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
            authorities.add(authority);
            user.setAuthorities(authorities);
            userService.createUser(user);
            response = ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                    .body(user);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response = ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body("An exception occured due to " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(Authentication authentication) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.getUserByUsername(authentication.getName()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/promoteUser")
    public boolean promoteUser (@RequestParam String username) {
        return userService.promoteUser(username);
    }

    @GetMapping("/demoteUser")
    public boolean demoteUser (@RequestParam String username) {
        return userService.demoteUser(username);
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "successful";
    }
}
```

And here is my React login component that i fetch the request:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useAuth } from '../../context/AuthContext'
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Login.css'
import logo from '../../images/logo.jpg'
import Input from '@mui/material/Input';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Visibility from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility';
import VisibilityOff from '@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff';
import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import {LoginService} from '../../services'
import { login } from '../../services/auth/LoginService'
import {encode as base64_encode} from 'base-64';



function Login() {

  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

 
  const handleClickShowPassword = () => setShowPassword((show) => !show);

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  
  const navigate = useNavigate ()
  const location = useLocation ()

  const {setUser} = useAuth ()


  async function loginUser (username, password) {

    let authHeader = username + ':'+password
    let encoded = base64_encode(authHeader)

    return fetch (
      "http://localhost:8083/api/auth/login", 
      {
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
          'Authorization' : 'Basic '+encoded,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Content-Type, Authorization, Password'
        },
        mode : 'no-cors'

      })
      
  }

  const loginHandle = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading (true)

    const response = await loginUser (username, password)
    

    console.log ('response :', response)

    response.json ()




   


    /*
    setUser (
      {
        username : 'ademgalitekin',
        password : 'password',
        id : 1
      }
    )
    */

    //set işleminden yani loginden sonra anasayfaya git
    navigate (location?.state?.return_url || '/')
  }

  const usernameOnChange = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value)
  }

  const passwordOnChange = (e) => {
    setPassword (e.target.value)
  }


  return (
    <div id='login'>
      <div id='img-container'>
        <img src={logo} alt='logo' style={{borderRadius : '100%'}}></img>
      </div>
      <TextField sx={{ m: 1, width: '30%', marginLeft : '32%'}}
          label="Kullanıcı Adı"
          id="standard-size-normal"
          variant="standard"
          style={{marginTop : '100px'}}
          onChange={usernameOnChange}
        />
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '30%', marginLeft : '32%'}} variant="standard" style={{marginTop : '20px'}}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">Parola</InputLabel>
          <Input
            id="standard-adornment-password"
            type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            onChange={passwordOnChange}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                >
                  {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
        <Box sx={{ '& > button': { m: 1 } }}>
        <LoadingButton
          onClick={loginHandle}
          loading={loading}
          variant="outlined"
          style={{width : '25%', height : '40px', marginLeft : '35%', backgroundColor : '#64A388', color : 'white', marginTop : '25px'}}
        >
          {loading ? '' : 'Giriş Yap'}
        </LoadingButton>
        
      </Box>
        
        

    </div>
  )
}


export default Login
```